# NextJS: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, getstaticprops, getstaticpaths, ssg

While usign the `getStaticPaths()` and `getStaticProps()` I am getting the error **NextJS: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in getStaticPaths() I was directly returning an array of strings as paths:

**Wrong Code**

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {    
 ...

    return {
      paths: ['product1','product2','product3'], //WRONG
      fallback: 'blocking'
    }
}
```

The solution was to return the paths array in a diffent structure:

**Correct Code**

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {    
 ...

    return {
      paths: [
          {'params': {myPageSlug: 'product1'}},
          {'params': {myPageSlug: 'product2'}},
          {'params': {myPageSlug: 'product3'}},
      ], //OK
      fallback: 'blocking'
    }
}
```

`myPageSlug` is the slug used when naming the page file, example: *pages/[myPageSlug].tsx*

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere in your file you might be using .toLowerCase() method and the conversion is not happening because the value is either undefined or not a string.

You can use something like Optional chaining (?.) operator to avoid this error.

You can learn more about [optional chaining operator here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)